# Problema con ORM Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Trabajando con Django, he creado mi modelo:

```
class Grupos(models.Model):
    group=models.TextField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Grupo de investigación')
    url=models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='URL Grupo')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group
```

Trabajando con el ORM (Ya he hecho todas las migraciones) quiero extraer toda la info de la base de datos y hago lo siguiente:

```
from scrap.models import Grupos

#Select * from tabla
query=Grupos
print(query.url)
```

Sin embargo, no me saca los 2 campos de mi base de datos (group y url), solo me saca el primero, group

```
<QuerySet [<Grupos: Metabolismo del DNA>, <Grupos: Inestabilidad Genomica y Cancer>, <Grupos: Genetica de Hongos de Interes Aplicado>, <Grupos: Mecanismos de Muerte Celular en Enfermedades Neurodegenerativas>]>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque te está regresando un objeto `QuerySet`. Este es básicamente un iterado que contiene datos, en este caso todos los registros que trajo la consulta en forma de objeto `Grupos`. Es decir, el `print` que haces, cuando te regresa `<Grupos: Metabolismo del DNA>` te está indicando que es de clase `Grupos` y lo de adelante es una breve descripción que al no especificarla, regresa el primer elemento del objeto.

Para obtener por ejemplo la url, te recomiendo hacer de esta forma.

```
from scrap.models import Grupos

#Select * from tabla
grupos=Grupos.objects.all() //forma correcta de hacer el query según la doc de Django
for grupo in grupos:
   print(grupo.url, grupo.group)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!